# Why is my code blocking while is instroducing data from a matrix of doubles into a file in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, file-io, block, ofstream

Im trying to introduce numbers of my matrix of doubles into a file, but my matrix is of 15000x15000 and when my code starts to introduce numbers into file, it blocks.

Why is my code blocking there?

i cut execution and when i opened the file, it had been writen, so i think that functions works, but it never ends, because my matrix its to big.

This is my code:

```
double **generarMatriz()
{
    double **M;

    M = new double *[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        M[i] = new double[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {

            if (i == j)
                M[i][j] = 1.0;

            else if (i > j)
                M[i][j] = (double)50 * (i + 1) * (j + 1) / (N + N); // Triangular inferior

            else
                M[i][j] = (double)-50 * (i + 1) * (j + 1) / (N + N); // Triangular superior
        }
    }
    return M;
}

void crearFicheros(double **&M, string nombreFicheroMatriz)
{
    ifstream infile(nombreFicheroMatriz);

    auto t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (infile)
    {
        infile.close();
        fstream outfile;

        outfile.open(nombreFicheroMatriz, ios_base::in);
        printf("Fichero ya existente");

        M = new double *[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            M[i] = new double[N];
        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                outfile >> M[i][j];
            }
        }
        auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        msGenerarMatriz = t2 - t1;
    }
    else
    {
        ofstream outfile(nombreFicheroMatriz);

        //outfile.open(nombreFicheroMatriz);

        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        M = generarMatriz();
        auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        msGenerarMatriz = t2 - t1;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                outfile << M[i][j] << " ";
            }
            outfile << endl;;
        }
        outfile.close();
    }
    auto t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    msGuardadoMatriz = t4 - t3;
}

void iterar()
{
    double **M;
    int m;
    string nombreFicheroTexto, nombreFicheroMatriz;
    auto t5 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    pedirIteraciones(m, nombreFicheroMatriz, nombreFicheroTexto);
    crearFicheros(M, nombreFicheroMatriz);
    auto t7 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    iterativo(M, nombreFicheroMatriz, nombreFicheroTexto, m);
    auto t8 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto t6 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    tiempoGlobal = t6 - t5;
    tiempoEjecucion = t8 - t7;

    filetext << "Tiempo de ejecución de la matriz: " << tiempoEjecucion.count() << "ms" << endl;
    filetext << "Tiempo global: " << tiempoGlobal.count() << "ms" << endl;
    filetext.close();
}
```

Comment: I doubt that it's actually "blocking".  Allocating a 2 gigabyte array, filling it, and writing it to disk takes a fair amount of time.

Comment: Where exactly is it blocking? Maybe add some debug messages to the console to ensure it is still going. Like after every `j` loop: `std::cout << "Wrote row " << i << "\n";` This will slow things down but you will know it's working.

Comment: It is not blocking at all. It is writting indefinitely the matrix into a file, and it never ends. But if i open the output file, after a few seconds of writting, the file has numbers, so outfile works, but it never ends.

Comment: I would wait a minutes, not seconds. Also, a minor speed up is to replace `endl` with `\n` because `endl` causes a flush that might slow you down a bit.

Comment: i waited during 3 minuts, but it didnt finish. I need an speed code, because i must do more thing with it. id like to speed up it, maybe with another faster library than fstream?